# login page in phonegap using database in mySql

Tags: php, android, cordova

i am designing a project in phonegap with android. i want to make a login page. i have stored my database in mySql in XXamp. user will enter name and password validation should be done by php page. after validation on php page, php page  will send feedback, according to  that feedback phonegap screen message whether user is valid or unvalid. please suggest me how can i access php page from phonegap application. I need help.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar questions were asked before take a look at this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385335/iphone-native-app-using-phonegap-and-php)

**All your PHP code will have to reside in a remote server**.

**However using phonegap you can load a website that runs PHP**

**To get data from the server you have to use the XMLHttpRequest object or jquery's $.get() or $.post() functions.**

You will get lot of examples pls google abt $.get() or $.post() functions.

Comment: The linked question is not very similar. OP specifically wants to know how to implement login, authentication and sessions in PhoneGap.